# Combine 2 Boolean columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I  have a **table** with few flag columns.(3 agencies rated bank; all cases mutually exclusive => at one time only one flag was ON. If flag1 has a value, flag2 and flag3 wont have any value and so on)

```
  BankName     Flag1       Flag2    Flag3  
    B1         TRUE         
    B2                                FALSE
    B3                      TRUE
    B4          FALSE  
    B5                       TRUE
```

and so on.

What I want:

```
  BankName     Flag1       Flag2    Flag3   Anyflag  
    B1         TRUE                           TRUE 
    B2                               FALSE    FALSE
    B3                      TRUE              TRUE
    B4          FALSE                         FALSE   
    B5                       TRUE             TRUE
```

Basically I wish to combine the flags overall in a separate column. I have tried **merge, concat and they dont seem to work on boolean columns.**

Tried:

```
[IN]:
df['Any flag']=pd.concat(df['Flag1'], df['Flag2'], df['Flag3'])
[OUT]
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you 
passed an object of type "Series"
[IN]:
df['Any flag']=pd.concat(df['Flag1'], df['Flag2'], df['Flag3'], axis=0)
[OUT]
TypeError: concat() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi, what you have tried

Comment: You can use any() to find out if a list of booleans contain at least one true. any([True, False, False]) returns True. Can also be used with none values: any([None, None, False]) returns False.

Comment: Hi the flag1 , flag2 , flag3 etc are basically slices from another dataset. The value is blank for other two flags when 1 flag is on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `any(axis='columns')`

**Ex:**

```
data = [ ['B1', True, '', ''],
 ['B2', '', '', False],
 ['B3', '', True, ''],
 ['B4', False, '', ''],
 ['B5','', True, '']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['BankName', 'Flag1', 'Flag2', 'Flag3'])
df["Anyflag"] = df[['Flag1', 'Flag2', 'Flag3']].any(axis='columns')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  BankName  Flag1 Flag2  Flag3  Anyflag
0       B1   True                  True
1       B2               False    False
2       B3         True            True
3       B4  False                 False
4       B5         True            True
```